# babel-preset-es2015 Failed to compile destructuring assignment syntax

Tags: variable-assignment, destructuring

I'm using babel to compile some es6 code, when I trying destructuring assignment it work well for array , but not Object destructuring. the problem code are as follow.

```
test(){
  var {a, b, ...rest} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40};
  console.log(a);
  console.log(rest);
}
```

the error log:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (11:13)

   9 | test(){
  10 | 
> 11 |   var {a, b, ...rest} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40};
     |              ^
  12 | 
  13 |   console.log(a);
  14 |   console.log(rest);

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/js/index.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = { 
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },  

  module:{
    loaders: [
      {   
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query:{
          presets:['react', 'es2015']
        },
      },  
      {   
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
      }   
    ]   
  },  

}
```

anyone had solved the same problem? hope for you help thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es2015 does not include spread properties, you can add a plugin to transform them

Take a look at this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread) and add this preset to your presets property

Answer (score 1):

Install babel-preset-env by running following command on terminal

```
npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

Then create .babelrc file in your project and write following JSON

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

for more information follow following link 
[babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/)